# jackson2 - unexpected field in JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to write a JSON from a java object. Everything works fine until I write the values to a String using the ObjectMapper. The String shows an unexpected field in the JSON document called "map".

I want this:

```
{
  "name": [
    {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3",
        "d": "4",
        "e": "5",
        "f": "6"
    }
  ]
}
```

I get this:

```
 {
  "name": [
    {
      "map": {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3",
        "d": "4",
        "e": "5",
        "f": "6"
      }
  ]
}
```

This is the class where I've defined the Object I want to convert to JSON:

```
public class SomeClass{
    private List<JSONObject> name;

//getters, setters
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem. I just created an array of object and then I've serialized it with jackson.

```
private Bla[] bla;
// getters and setters
```

Class Bla:

```
private String a;
private String b;
private String c;
...
// getters and setters
```

Thank you for everything.

Jon

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that inside the class you are serializing you have a parameter called `map` if you called it `bla` you would have seen:

```
{
  "name": [
{
  "bla": {
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2",
    "c": "3",
    "d": "4",
    "e": "5",
    "f": "6"
  }
 ]
}
```

in order to get rid of the parameter name you should use the annotation: `@JsonUnwrapped` on top of the `map` parameter inside the class, like:

```
@JsonUnwrapped
private Map<String, String> map;
```

Another option is to create a getter function for `map` use the following:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
return mapper.writeValueAsString(map.getDataMap());
```

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin, yes. This annotation is available in Jackson 1.9+.

Comment: AFAIK, `@JsonAnyGetter` / `@JsonAnySetter` should be used for `Map`s instead of  `@JsonUnwrapped`.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin, `@JsonAnyGetter` is used on a generic getter function. The annotation `@JsonUnwrapped` is being used on the map variable itself without creating a special getter. This will allow you to return the values within the map without the map being displayed in the JSON itself.

Comment: @eladyanai, I'm not using any parameter called map in the class I am trying to serialize. You have the class in my question.

Comment: @JayMash, can you post the code you are using to add elements to the list?